# How to pass multiple queries into loop for tweepy bot

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

This is my first python project, so bear with me! I have been watching a youtube tutorial on how to code this script and I'm almost done. However, I don't understand how to pass multiple queries into the loop.

For example, if I add additional search options to "q" the script breaks. ex: q="#johnsoncity, #bristol, #kingsport".

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#Johnsoncitytn", lang='en').items():
try:

    if (tweet.user.id == myBot.id) or (myData.is_stored_b(str(tweet.id))):
        continue
    myData.add_data(str(tweet.id))
    print("\n\nFound tweet by: @" + tweet.user.screen_name)
```

Like I said, I'm pretty green when it comes to python. Thank you for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to figure out how to build the query, q, parameter is to visit the [Twitter Advanced Search Page](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) and look at the URL it creates when submitting the page.

For example, if you wanted to match one of those tags, you could query like this:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#johnsoncity or #bristol or #kingsport", lang='en').items():
    # your other code ...
    print("\n\nFound tweet by: @" + tweet.user.screen_name)
```

Notice how I replaced your commas with `or`.